# How to move/copy a file and rename if conflict

Tags: javascript, file, wakanda

Is there some API/Library to move or copy a file and then have an option to rename the new file if there is a conflict with another file existing in the destination?

I am using Wakanda and there is a [File API](http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.fr.html#/Files-and-Folders/File.201-664957.en.html) which has a [moveTo](http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.fr.html#/Files-and-Folders/File/moveTo.301-672801.en.html) method. This method has an parameter which is `overwrite`, if we pass `true` or '`Overwrite`' and `false` or '`KeepExisting`'. This method forget one option, which is a classic when dealing with file, is : '`KeepBoth`'. That mean it gonna rename the new file with a counter.

For now, I add an UUID at the end of the file.

I'm wondering how other API handle this case when we need to move and rename in case of conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you will use ajax and call a server side script to check if the file exists. You could add a number to the file name to prevent a conflict.

PHP example

```
$path = "link/to/path";
$chk = $path;
$i = 0;

while (file_exists($chk)){
    $chk = $path.$i
    $i++;
}
```

If you want to overwrite it you would simply use

```
file_put_contents($path, $content);
```

Comment: Thanks, this example is good for PHP. My question is about server-side javascript. 

I see in the method `file_put_contents`, there is a `FILE_APPEND` parameter which will rename the file. It is exactly that kind of parameter I am looking for, in an existing API

Comment: server side js means you use nodejs?